# How do i filter already seen episodes from a show in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have something like this:[image]

We  saved an item for user, show and episode on ES.

We need to list the episodes of a show but we need to remove from that list the episodes the user already watched.

We have some ideas, like saving an array of watched episodes, but we are concern because the array of watched episodes is expected to scale.

I'll appreciate any recommendation in how to do it.

We are thinking on saving an array of watched episodes and filter the ES query, but we are concerned about the size of that array, because it is expected to scale.

The other thing that we think is creating a list of episodes for each user but that seems excessive.

Is there a solution where we can save an item on ES with the watched episode Id and the user Id, and remove those items from the over all episode list from the show.

Comment: From what I understand you want to register a data and remove an item from a list. Is all this in the same index?
Do you want this logic to be elastic's responsibility?

Comment: @rabbitbr Yes all the data is on the same index, and i was hoping ES could remove the already seen episode from the list

Comment: You can use the update by query for remove the item in list. Your list is nested type?

Answer (score 0):

you can update a document and it will overwrite the existing one in Elasticsearch. logically it'd work like this;

1. user watches episode 1
2. app gets list of episodes from Elasticsearch
3. app removes watched episode from list
4. app sends updated list back to Elasticsearch
5. Elasticsearch updates the doc without that episode

you still need to do that work outside of Elasticsearch, as it cannot run that logic for you